# simulating noise with Yuler and burg

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, python

I want to simulate short term white noise with  Yuler and Burg. It's said that it can give better results than Gauss-Markov.
The problem is that each time the series diverge. Do you think that I made a mistake in  my code
Burg

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt
from scipy import signal
from spectrum import *
from pylab import *


def simulate_noise_burg(self,x,ordre):#x = data series
    var=numpy.var(x)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, var**0.5, len(x))
    ar, variance, coeff_reflection = arburg(x, ordre)
    i=0
    tmp_ar=[]
    tmp_coef=[]
    while i<len(ar):
        tmp_ar.append(ar[i].real)
        tmp_coef.append(coeff_reflection[i].real)
        i+=1

    last_elements=np.array(tmp_ar)
    coeff_reflection=np.array(tmp_coef)

    result=[]
    i=0
    new_element=0
    while i<len(x): 
        new_element= last_elements.dot(coeff_reflection)+ noise[i]
        resultat.append(float(new_element))
        j=1
        while j<len(last_elements):
            last_elements[j]=last_elements[j-1]
            j+=1
        last_elements[0]=new_element
        i+=1
    return result
```

Yuler

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt
from scipy import signal
from spectrum import *
from pylab import *


def simulate_noise_yuler (self,x,ordre):#x = data series
    var=np.var(x)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, var**0.5, len(x))
    ar, variance, coeff_reflection = aryule(x, ordre)

    last_elements=np.array(ar)

    tmp_coef=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(coeff_reflection):
        tmp_coef.append([coeff_reflection[i]])
        i+=1
    coef=np.array(tmp_coef)

    result=[]
    i=0
    new_element=0
    while i<len(x): 
        new_element= last_elements.dot(coef)+ noise[i]
        resultat.append(float(new_element))
        j=1
        while j<len(last_elements):
            last_elements[j]=last_elements[j-1]
            j+=1
        last_elements[0]=new_element
        i+=1
    return result
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yuler  code :

```
    def simulate_noise_YULER (self,data_to_simulat,ordre):
    ar, var, coeff_reflection = aryule(data_to_simulat, ordre)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, var**0.5, len(data_to_simulat))

    ar=np.array(ar)
    elements=np.array([0]*ar.size)
    result=[]
    i=0
    new_element=0
    while i<len(data_to_simulat): 
        new_element= elements.dot(ar)+ noise[i]
        result.append(float(new_element))
        j=0
        while j<len(elements)-1:
            elements[j+1]=elements[j]
            j+=1
        elements[0]=new_element
        i+=1
    return result
```

and Burg :

```
    def simulate_noise_BURG(self,data_to_simulat,ordre):
    ar, var, coeff_reflection = arburg(data_to_simulat, ordre)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, var**0.5, len(data_to_simulat))

    i=0
    tmp_ar=[]
    while i<len(ar):
        tmp_ar.append(ar[i].real)
        i+=1

    ar=np.array(tmp_ar)

    elements=np.array([0]*ar.size)

    result=[]
    new_element=0
    i=0

    while i<len(data_to_simulat): 
        new_element= elements.dot(ar)+ noise[i]
        result.append(float(new_element))
        j=0
        while j<len(elements)-1:
            elements[j+1]=elements[j]
            j+=1
        elements[0]=new_element
        i+=1

    return result
```